# Zoom on UITextField

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield, zooming

I am working on an iOS application which contains of many UIView's. UINavigation is used to navigate between those views.

One of my UIView contains UITextField. My problem is that, when I zoom it display the content of another view. I had not added any code for zooming.

Below is screen shot of my actual design.[image: Actual Design]

On zoom, It display's the root view of navigation
[image]

Also, it work properly on simulator. This problem is detected when I had tested application on device.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved this problem. The real problem was with `PPRevealSideViewController`. I had implemented `PPRevealSideViewController` and the flow was not properly set. So the root view in `PPRevealSideViewController` was having the highest window level and thus on zooming it was displaying content of that view.